# Plotly background color

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plotly plot that looks like below
[Plotly plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7boj.png)

In the plot, i have `numbers` in y axis , i want to color them in a range. For example, from `0 to 20` i want `pink` color for all the values in x axis, from `20 to 40` i want `red` color and so on. How can i do this. I see a `layout` option in plotly like below

```
layout = go.Layout(title='Simple Plot from csv data',
                   plot_bgcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)')
```

How can i manipulate this to get the result i want.

Comment: Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly with `plot_bgcolor` for different sections of the bakcground. But you can easily obtain the desired effect with [`shapes`](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#highlighting-time-series-regions-with-rectangle-shapes) like this:

```
colors = ['pink', 'red']
shapes = []
bgs = [[0, 20], [20, 40]]
for i, b in enumerate(bgs):
    shapes.append(dict(type="rect",
                xref="paper",
                yref="y",
                x0=0,
                y0=b[0],
                x1=1,
                y1=b[1],
                fillcolor=colors[i],
                opacity=0.5,
                layer="below",
                line_width=0))
```

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.gapminder().query("country=='Canada'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", title='Life expectancy in Canada')
x = x = np.arange(10)
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=x**2))

colors = ['pink', 'red']
shapes = []
bgs = [[0, 20], [20, 40]]
for i, b in enumerate(bgs):
    shapes.append(dict(type="rect",
                xref="paper",
                yref="y",
                x0=0,
                y0=b[0],
                x1=1,
                y1=b[1],
                fillcolor=colors[i],
                opacity=0.5,
                layer="below",
                line_width=0))

fig.update_layout(#xaxis=dict(showgrid=False),
                  shapes=shapes)
fig.show()
```